# JNI - difference between JNIEnv and JavaVM

Tags: java, java-native-interface

> As we know **JNIEnv** is the pointer to the VM.
>
> And as name suggests **JavaVM** is a VM itself.
>
> *Is there any difference between them?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As we know JNIEnv is the pointer to the VM

It isn't.
`JNIEnv` is an alias for a `struct _JNIEnv`, which in turn contains a `JNINativeInterface*` and a bunch of methods (`FindClass`, `GetMethodID`, `NewLocalRef`, etc).
When you call a method through your `JNIEnv*`, the call is delegated to the `JNINativeInterface` instance, which contains function pointers to the actual implementations provided by the runtime.

A `JavaVM` on the other hand is an alias for a `struct _JavaVM`, which contains a `JNIInvokeInterface*`. The `JNIInvokeInterface` has a different set of methods (e.g. `GetEnv`, `AttachCurrentThread`) compared to the `JNINativeInterface`.

---

So they have different purposes. The main purpose of a `JavaVM*` is to allow you to obtain a `JNIEnv*` that is valid for the current thread of execution. The `JNIEnv*` is what you need to resolve Java classes, call Java methods, etc.